# I cannot install django onto macos using pip

Tags: python, django, macos, terminal, pip

I'm new to python and I'm trying to install Django onto my MacBook. I am following the documentation on the site from
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/install/#installing-official-release
using

```
$ python -m pip install Django
```

but I get this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-21.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/__main__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-21.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm not sure what the issue is. I might have a bugged version of pip. I'm not sure. Like I said I'm fairly new to all this so help would really be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try installing Django using python3 since python is alias to python2.7 on macos (for now bigSur):

```sh
python3 -m pip install Django
```

This will install it globally of course. It is worth looking into creating a development python environment (https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed the issue, I will look into the environment. I had been struggling with this for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're using venv but definitely use it.

You're on Python 2.7, which means you'll need Django 1.11.x or lower versions

> The Django 1.11.x series is the last to support Python 2.7.
>
> Django 2.0 will be the last release series to support Python 3.4. If you plan a deployment of Python 3.4 beyond the end-of-life for Django 2.0 (April 2019), stick with Django 1.11 LTS (supported until April 2020) instead. Note, however, that the end-of-life for Python 3.4 is March 2019.

Comment: Mac OS X comes with python 2.7 out of the box, but I highly recommend updating your Python version to a newer version using `brew`